# Apply type projection to a refined type

Tags: scala, type-safety, type-projection, refined

Consider the following example:

```
trait T3

trait T2{
  type TT4
  type TT3 <: T3
}

trait T1{
  type TT2 <: T2
}
```

now I want to write a function the roughly speaking looks as

```
def test[T <: T1](t: T#TT2{type TT4 = Int}#TT3) = println(t)  //invalid syntax
```

which unfortunately is not a valid syntax. It is perfectly possible to write a function like this

```
def test[T <: T1](t: T#TT2#TT3) = println(t)
```

But I'd like to add a bit stricter restriction on `T#TT2` making it to be a refined type `T#TT2{ type TT4 = Int}`.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping type `T#TT2 { type TT4 = Int }` in parenthesis before the final projection like so

```
def test[T <: T1](t: (T#TT2 { type TT4 = Int })#TT3) = ???
```

[Types](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html) can always be wrapped in parentheses

```
SimpleType        ::=  SimpleType TypeArgs
                      |  SimpleType ‘#’ id
                      |  StableId
                      |  Path ‘.’ ‘type’
                      |  Literal
                      |  ‘(’ Types ‘)’      <======= note the parentheses
```

for example

```
scala> val xs: (List[(Int)]) = List(42)
val xs: List[Int] = List(42)
```